# How to execute a method having parameters more than once concurrently?

Tags: java, multithreading, sorting, concurrency, threadpool

This is the java program for Bitonic sort.
Since bitonic sort is a parallel sorting algorithm. I want to execute the exchange(...) method in the below class concurrentl. But I am getting "variable i should be final" when i try to create a thread for the each method call.

```
Thread[] t = new Thread[k];
            for (int i = beg; i < beg + k; i++) {
                t[i - beg] = new Thread() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        exchange(a, i, i + k, d);
                    }
                };
                t[i - beg].start();
            }
```

Suppose if i include this in the below merge method it is showing "
Local variable i defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final
"

Bitonic.java

```
package datastructures;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class BitonicSort {
    static int[] a;

    static void exchange(int a[], int i, int j, int d) {
        int temp;
        if ((a[i] > a[j] && d == 1) || (a[i] < a[j] && d == 0)) {
            temp = a[i];
            a[i] = a[j];
            a[j] = temp;
        }
    }

    static void merge(int beg, int c, int d) {
        if (c > 1) {
            int k = c / 2;

            for (int i = beg; i < beg + k; i++) {

                exchange(a, i, i + k, d);
            }
            Thread t1 = new Thread() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    merge(beg, k, d);
                }
            };
            t1.start();

            Thread t2 = new Thread() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    merge(beg + k, k, d);
                }
            };
            t2.start();

            try {
                t1.join();
                t2.join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }

    static void bitonicSort(int beg, int c, int d) {
        if (c > 1) {
            int k = c / 2;

            Thread t1 = new Thread() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    bitonicSort(beg, k, 1);
                }
            };
            t1.start();

            Thread t2 = new Thread() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    bitonicSort(beg + k, k, 0);
                }
            };
            t2.start();

            try {
                t1.join();
                t2.join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            merge(beg, c, d);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FastReader reader = new FastReader();
        System.out.println("Please enter the no.of elements:");
        int n = 0;
        try {
            n = reader.nextInt();
            if ((n & n - 1) != 0)
                throw new Exception("Given n is not a power of 2");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        a = new int[n];
        System.out.println("Please enter the elements:");
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            a[i] = reader.nextInt();
        bitonicSort(0, n, 1);
        System.out.println("\nElements after sorting are: " + Arrays.toString(a));
    }
}
```

I have tried different approaches but none of them worked. I have searched the stackoverflow also but no relevant ans for my problem.

Anyhelp would be appreciated.

I have tried different approaches but none of them worked. I have searched the stackoverflow also but no relevant ans for my problem.

Anyhelp would be appreciated.

Comment: This is a pretty common problem for which the solution is "make another local variable to copy the value of `i`, and use that in the implementation instead."

Comment: I have tried but the error still remained the same.

Comment: Thread[] t = new Thread[k];
   for (int i = beg; i < beg + k; i++) {
    t[i - beg] = new Thread() {
     int j = i;

     @Override
     public void run() {
      exchange(a, j, j + k, d);
     }
    };
   }

Comment: Move `int j = i` outside of `new Thread() { ... }`.

Comment: Thank you very much it has got worked. But how? Though previously I defined variable I as static in a new thread() {...} it didn't work.

Comment: That would make things worse.